# Why is undefined being returned in this code?

Tags: javascript

I have the following module to set and read a key/name pair. Every time I call Store.save('name','Jason')" undefined is returned and I'm not sure why. Any ideas as to why this is happening would be much appreciated. Here's the code:

```
var config = {
    trackEvents: ['focus', 'blur'],
    trackFields: ['input[type=text]', 'select', 'input[type=radio]', 'input[type=checkbox]'],
    currentFocused: '',
    lastFocused: '',
    enableDoNotTrack: false,
    debug: true,
    cookieExpiry: 30
};

var Store = (function () {
    // Set keyvalue pair in either localstorage or a cookie
    function _set(key, value) {
        // If value detected set or modify the key
        if (typeof value !== "undefined" && value !== null) {
            if (localStorage) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } else {
                _setCookie(key, value, config.cookieExpiry);
            }
        }
        // if value is null or undefined, delete the key
        if (value === null) {
            if (localStorage) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            } else {
                _setCookie(key, null, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    function _get(key) {
        var val = '';
        if (localStorage) {
            val = localStorage.getItem(key);
        } else {
            val = _getCookie(key);
        }
        return val;
    }

    // Set cookie
    function _setCookie(key, value, exp) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exp * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = key + "=" + value + "; " + expires;
    }

    // Read cookie  
    function _getCookie(key) {
        var name = key + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
    return {
        save: _set,
        read: _get
    };
})(config);
```

Comment: Do you mean `Store.set` or `Store.save`? Because `Store.set` would be undefined. Your IIFE returns an object with a `save` and a `read` only.

Comment: You are missing quotes -> `Store.set('name','Jason')`

Comment: Along with the name issue, your _set method doesn't return anything so you would get undefined

Comment: Apologies... I did mean Store.save(). If that's the right behaviour then that's great. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The object returned from "Store" doesn't have a "set" property. It's got a "save" property, however, whose value is a reference to the "_set" function in the closure.

*edit* and as pointed out in a comment by Patrick Evans, the "_set" method doesn't return a value, so even if you were to correctly call "save", it'd return `undefined`.

Comment: …and even `Store.save()` does return `undefined`.

Comment: Apologies... I did mean Store.save(). If that's the right behaviour then I guess that's fine, or I can return a value.